# Testing a service call to Restangular with nested spy

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, restangular

the service I'm testing has this function (for example):

```
doSomething : function(userID,boolean){

                var t = otherService.getSomething();
                var params = somedata;
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                if (boolean){
                    Restangular.one("users",userID).post("copy",params).then(function(data){...
```

And I just want to with a spy on Restangular to see if it gets the right params, endpoints etc to use.

so I made a restangular mock:

```
mockRestangular = {
                    one:function(){return this}
                    },



                    post:function(){

                    },
                    all:function(){

                    }
                };
                    },

//also tried:
// one: function(){return {post:function(){}};}


                };
```

but I can't set a jasmine spy on the nested post in the mock:

`spyOn(mockRestangular.one,'post')` I get `post() method does not exist`

and the function call fails too

`someService.doSomething(params)`

because it can find the post method.

Notice that I need the post method to be nested to the one method. If i just turn one into an object It would fail with a missing `one` method.

Guess I'm missing something obvious but I've been wrapping my mind around this all morning and failed completely

**EDIT:**

Adding `andCallThrough()` to the spy had all the pieces settled in the right direction. I'll update in an answer if someone would come looking some day.

Comment: Where is the mock injected? Do you think you could create a plunker?

Comment: thanks for the help, but I just figured it out, when I used ```andCallThrough()``` with the spy, everything started to work in the right direction. Not very intuitive, at least for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was:
adding to the first spy:

```
spyOn(mockRestangular,'one').andCallThrough();
```

and change the object to:

```
mockRestangular = {
                    one:function(){
                         return this //since this can be chained to another one or post method, this way it always has one...
                    },



                    post:function(){

                    },
                    all:function(){

                    }
                };
```

**Edit:** I moved to Sinon, jasmine spys are too limited anyway.

**Edit:** This is how to move to chai+sinon in karma/jasmine testing (without moving to mocha..):

```
npm install karma-sinon-chai
```

Add to karma.conf.js:

add it in the `plugins` list

```
'karma-sinon-chai'
```

and in change the framework:

```
    frameworks: ['jasmine','sinon-chai'],
```

Now add a `chai-helper.js` file (name doesn't matter) to the `files` array in the karma.conf file.

the file should include:

```
var should = chai.should(); //you don't need all three, just the style you prefer.. 
var expect = chai.expect; //notice that using would break existing test and need you to do a little rewrite to fix the matchers. if you don't want to, comment this line out
var assert = chai.assert;
```

Comment: care to share the solution?

Comment: @TomažZaman edited the answer with setup instructions for sinon and chai. Although this is really solved by mock ```all``` and ```one``` returning ```this``` and by that allow the Restangular chaining